# Reveal page based on a fan's username

Tags: facebook-like, discount

I have a fan gate/ reveal page on Facebook. When the user likes the page, the user goes to a second page and the user is able to download a PDF file. I want to generate the content of the PDF file dynamically so that it includes the username of the user/fan. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

To get the users name you would need to have them authenticate with your application - liking a page does not give the users info to the liked page.